# Need help on building the right mixed models’ formula!

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

In the experiment 25 alpine skiers did a pretest (3 runs), two training sessions (5 run each) and a posttest (3 runs), during the training sessions I split skiers in two different groups and they trained with two different methods.

I have two hypothesis where I think one group will outperform the other one.

1. Learning: where I think one group will outperform the other one at POSTTEST
2. Performance: where I think one group will outperform the other one during the two training sessions

My dataset looks like this: (if you need more I can send you)

```
structure(list(BIB. = structure(c(10L, 25L, 22L, 7L, 8L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29"), class = "factor"), Gruppe = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), levels = c("EF", "IF"), class = "factor"), Run = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), `Performance Time` = c(3.265, 2.665, 2.295, 2.87, 1.245
), Session = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Pretest", 
"Trening 1", "Trening 2", "Posttest"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have also been making dummy variable (1 if in group, 0 if not) of these;
D_gruppe
Session_Pretest
`Session_Trening 1`
`Session_Trening 2`
Session_Posttest

```
Learning <- lmer(Performance_Time ~ D_gruppe*Session_Pretest*Session_Posttest 
              + (1|BIB.) + (1|Performance_Time), data)




Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error        df t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 1.73745    0.17672  23.20492   9.832 0.00000000096228820 ***
D_gruppe                   -0.28826    0.25404  22.74112  -1.135             0.26833    
Session_Pretest             0.54241    0.06464 333.00002   8.392 0.00000000000000139 ***
Session_Posttest           -0.02623    0.06556 331.96347  -0.400             0.68934    
D_gruppe:Session_Pretest    0.29673    0.09086 315.22625   3.266             0.00121 ** 
D_gruppe:Session_Posttest   0.24381    0.09508 311.20751   2.564             0.01081 *

NB: Fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients
```

```
Performance  <- lmer(Performance_Time ~ D_gruppe*`Session_Trening 1`*`Session_Trening 2` + (1|BIB.)+ (1|Performance_Time), data)


Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error        df t value        Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      2.01527    0.17963  23.91889  11.219 0.0000000000518 ***
D_gruppe1                       -0.01327    0.25922  23.83809  -0.051        0.959600    
`Session_Trening 1`1            -0.25319    0.06520 331.15639  -3.883        0.000124 ***
`Session_Trening 2`1            -0.30096    0.06997 308.15178  -4.301 0.0000228229014 ***
D_gruppe1:`Session_Trening 1`1  -0.15125    0.09436 288.25119  -1.603        0.110045    
D_gruppe1:`Session_Trening 2`1  -0.40798    0.09864 284.29362  -4.136 0.0000465465789 ***

NB: Fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients
```

```
Combi  <- lmer(Performance_Time ~ D_gruppe*Session_Pretest*`Session_Trening 1`*`Session_Trening 2`*Session_Posttest
             + (1|BIB.) + (1|Performance_Time), data)


Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error        df t value          Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      1.71698    0.18437  26.29124   9.313 0.000000000822521 ***
D_gruppe1                       -0.05889    0.26648  26.37089  -0.221          0.826791    
Session_Pretest1                 0.57474    0.07644 329.70574   7.518 0.000000000000529 ***
`Session_Trening 1`1             0.03276    0.06853 331.09471   0.478          0.632962    
`Session_Trening 2`1            -0.01135    0.07201 324.09671  -0.158          0.874802    
D_gruppe1:Session_Pretest1       0.05871    0.11083 324.39636   0.530          0.596656    
D_gruppe1:`Session_Trening 1`1  -0.09119    0.10106 318.79226  -0.902          0.367565    
D_gruppe1:`Session_Trening 2`1  -0.37456    0.10321 311.02413  -3.629          0.000332 ***



NB: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 24 columns / coefficients
```

I’m pretty new to mixed models an im not sure If I have been building the right mixed models’ formula? And I if I can answer my two hypothesis with this approach.

Comment: Thank you @peter861222!

Comment: Why `Performance_Time` as a response *and* as a random effect?

Comment: @usεr11852, thank you for the comment! The reason is that every subject (BIB.) vary their performance a lot, some perform worse overtime and some performance better overtime. The conditions off the snow can also influence how they perform and that can vary for the groups so that's why I put it as a random effect is that correct?

Comment: No, you should not put Performance_time in as random effect. It makes no sense to assume clustering by levels of the response variable, and you can't use a continuous variable as a random effect anyway. Your random effect of BIB. takes care of the issue of performance times clustering within different participants. If you think Performance time is also clustered within overtime vs. non-overtime, you can add a random effect of overtime. But using your continuous dependent variable as random effect is not something you should do.

Comment: Thank you @Sointu for commenting! I see, but what du you mean when you say “clustered within overtime vs. non-overtime”? I think D_gruppe then maybe can be used? lmer(Performance_Time ~ D_gruppe*Session + (1|BIB./ D_gruppe), data)

Comment: I was just trying to figure out what you were trying to do by including the (1|Performance_time) as a random effect, and since you mentioned overtime, I thought that might have something to do with it. But I think your code in your original post is fine after you remove the (1|Performance_time) from the predictor side of your model script, I don't think you need to (or can) control for additional issues. Also, you can't put Gruppe in as random effect if you use it as a categorical fixed predictor (I would use it as you are using it now, as fixed predictor).

Comment: Thank you! @Sointu! Tried adding “run number” (when the athletes were measured) a random effect and that looks muche better

Comment: I'm glad it looks better!